# How to sort a list including intervals but in the string format

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list of string, which they were originally interval and I had to convert them to string. Now I want to sort the list based on the first number in the tuple.

Input list:

```
in_lst = ['(-100, 20)', '(100, 200)', '(20, 100)']
```

When I use the following code:

```
sorted(in_lst)
```

it returns the following:

```
['(-100, 20)', '(100, 200)', '(20, 100)']
```

While the expected output is

```
['(-100, 20)', '(20, 100)', '(100, 200)']
```

In addition, I would be able to handle inclusive boundaries like following:

```py
['(-100, 20]', '(100, 200]', '(20, 100]']
```

Comment: What are you trying to sort by? The first number in the tuple?

Comment: Why must these be strings? Makes more sense to have them as tuples?

Comment: Yes, the first number in the tuple!

Comment: @bigbounty - instead of `eval`, I would suggest `ast.literal_eval`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to work with intevals with both inclusive and exclusive boundaries, you could use [portion](https://github.com/AlexandreDecan/portion/blob/2.0.2/README.md) and its [from_string](https://github.com/AlexandreDecan/portion/blob/2.0.2/README.md#import--export-intervals-to-strings) function:

```py
import portion
portion.from_string('(-100, 20]', conv=int)
# (-100,20]
```

This function provides structures to handle intevals and thoses structures can be compared:

```py
interval_1 = portion.from_string('(-100, 20]', conv=int)
interval_2 = portion.from_string('(100, 200]', conv=int)

print(interval_1 <= interval_2)  # True
print(interval_1 >= interval_2)  # False
```

Thus, by converting your strings to interval structures, you are able to sort them. For convenience you probably want a function to handle this conversion, that you will be able to pass to the sorting function:

```py
l = ['(-100, 20]', '(100, 200]', '(20, 100]']

def string_to_interval(conv):
    def key_func(string):
        return portion.from_string(string, conv=conv)
    return key_func

print(sorted(l, key=string_to_interval(int)))
# ['(-100, 20]', '(20, 100]', '(100, 200]']
```

If your interval boudaries have been floats, you would use `sorted(l, key=string_to_interval(float))` instead

---

If you only need to work with exclusive boundaries, you could use [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to safely convert your strings to tuples:

```py
import ast


in_lst = ['(-100, 20)', '(100, 200)', '(20, 100)']

tuples = map(ast.literal_eval, in_lst)
```

Then you just have to sort your list of tuples:

```py
print(sorted(tuples))
# [(-100, 20), (20, 100), (100, 200)]
```

---

If you want to keep your strings, you could also provide `ast.literal_eval` as the comparison key to the [sorted](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/functions.html?highlight=sorted#sorted) function:

```py
print(sorted(in_lst, key=ast.literal_eval))
# ['(-100, 20)', '(20, 100)', '(100, 200)']
```

or even [sort](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=list%20sort#list.sort) the list in place:

```py
in_lst.sort(key=ast.literal_eval)
print(in_lst)
# ['(-100, 20)', '(20, 100)', '(100, 200)']
```

Comment: How about the case that the input list is in this way ['(-100, 20]', '(100, 200]', '(20, 100]']?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ast.literal_eval` as the key to sort

```
>>> import ast
>>> in_lst = ['(-100, 20)', '(100, 200)', '(20, 100)']
>>> 
>>> sorted(in_lst, key=ast.literal_eval)
['(-100, 20)', '(20, 100)', '(100, 200)']
```